# Seeking an explanation for Nezhmetidnov’s queen sacrifice

Tags: analysis, queens, sacrifice

In [this](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1260278) game, Rashid Nezhmetidnov sacrificed his queen for a bishop. I see that White gets an outpost on d5, but I can't find anything else that justifises the sacrifice. Is there any other compensation that exists?

```
[Title "Rashid Gibiatovich Nezhmetdinov-Oleg L Chernikov, Chigorin Team Cup, Rostov-on-Don USSR, 1962"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "22"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 g6 5. Nc3 Bg7 6. Be3 Nf6 7. Bc4 O-O 8. Bb3 Ng4 9. Qxg4 Nxd4 10. Qh4 Qa5 11. O-O Bf6 12. Qxf6 Ne2+ 13. Nxe2 exf6 14. Nc3 Re8 15. Nd5 Re6 16. Bd4 Kg7 17. Rad1 d6 18. Rd3 Bd7 19. Rf3 Bb5 20. Bc3 Qd8 21. Nxf6 Be2 22. Nxh7+ Kg8 23. Rh3 Re5 24. f4 Bxf1 25. Kxf1 Rc8 26. Bd4 b5 27. Ng5 Rc7 28. Bxf7+ Rxf7 29. Rh8+ Kxh8 30. Nxf7+ Kh7 31. Nxd8 Rxe4 32. Nc6 Rxf4+ 33. Ke2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

White doesn't get only one bishop for the queen, but two pieces: a bishop and a knight.

Moreover, Black's weak king, White's domination of the center, great outposts for his pieces and lack of prospects for Black's development (especially his rooks) fully compensate the material imbalance.

Comment: And most importantly: it just works! Sometimes principles can't give a full justification for a moves. There must be concrete variations supporting it

Answer (score 0):

Nezhmetdinov was a little crazy in chess terms. That's why so many people enjoy his games.

White gets two pieces for the queen, and chances on the kingside black squares. Black's d=pawn is backward on an open file, which makes d5 an ideal square for a knight.

Not the most speculative sacrifice of Nezhmetdinov's career.